# Derive drag coefficient of plate

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, viscosity

There is any analytical way to derive drag coefficient of flat plate aligned perpendicular to the flow? Wikipedia says it's between 1.98~2.05 but I want to get this value in calculation, not experimental value.

Comment: If you ask me your simplest bet would be to use the empirical relations given in any standard Heat Transfer Data Handbook!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. For laminar flows, the solution will be the [Blasius solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blasius_boundary_layer), but the solution is still numerical. There are analytical functions that can approximate it fairly well.

For turbulent boundary layers, there is even less hope for an analytical solution. The flow is non-linear and time dependent, but mean equations can be found. These will still need to be solved numerically though.

Although the flow configuration seems like it is one of the most basic possible, the Navier-Stokes equations admit relatively few known analytical solutions.

Comment: Frankly, I want to derive the relationship between the pressure on the building window and the velocity of the wind, this also can't find an analytical solution? turbulence problem also occurred in this situation?

Comment: @YeonJoonKim Well, one of the assumptions we make is that the pressure gradient across a boundary layer is zero. So if the wind is parallel to your window, if you know how fast the wind is moving you can assume the pressure at the surface is the same, and that will just be based on Bernoulli's equation. So that is simple at least. But in real life, there will be quite a bit of buffeting due to turbulence and it won't be nearly so simple of a problem.

Comment: If your plate is perpendicular to the flow, you can look up how stagnation point flows work. Again, it's a numerical solution. For example, [this paper](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/WCE2009/WCE2009_pp1673-1678.pdf) looks at pressure and drag.

Comment: @tpg2114  Isn't the Blasius solution for a plate aligned *parallel* to the flow.  The OP wants the drag coefficient for the plate aligned *perpendicular* to the flow.  If the flow is laminar, the flow can be solved using computational fluid dynamics.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Yes -- I realized the parallel vs perpendicular thing afterwards, that's why I added the comment about stagnation point flow which is the perpendicular equivalent. And even if the flow is turbulent, supersonic, chemically reacting plasma, CFD is always an option -- it isn't limited to laminar problems. But OP was specifically looking for an analytical solution and in any of the cases, there isn't one.